# Invalid CSP report with connect-src 'self'

Tags: content-security-policy

we have a rather strange error regarding CSP reports.

We're running an internal application with the Policy `script-src 'self'; default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://sentry.internal.domain.com; report-uri https://sentry.internal.domain.com/api/.....` in report-only mode (via the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header).

On various pages we have Javascript that fetches data from the application (via `fetch` and `jquery`). API endpoints and Javascript bundles are all loaded from the same domain, so `'self'` should always apply. And no insecure requests here; everything is loaded via https.

We're reporting CSP violations to our on-prem Sentry instance and have a lot of CSP violation - probably one for each XHR call, each with a violation of the `connect-src` directive.

However, i cannot reproduce the error at all. Developer tools across multiple browser show not CSP violations whatsoever. A negative test (adding a XHR call to an origin not listed in `connect-src`), shows the expected error in the developer console.

The relevant part of the Sentry event (I don't have access to the original CSP document):

```
{
"csp": {
  "effective_directive": "connect-src",
  "blocked_uri": "https://app.internal.domain.com/app/endpoint/",
  "document_uri": "https://app.internal.domain.com/app/",
  "original_policy": "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://sentry.internal.domain.com; default-src 'self'; report-uri https://sentry.internal.domain.com/api/16/security/?sentry_key=abcd",
  "referrer": "",
  "status_code": 200,
  "violated_directive": "connect-src",
  "disposition": "report"
},
"culprit": "connect-src",
"location": "app.internal.domain.com",
"logentry": {
  "formatted": "Blocked 'connect' from 'app.internal.domain.com'"
},
"metadata": {
  "directive": "connect-src",
  "message": "Blocked 'connect' from 'app.internal.domain.com'",
  "uri": "app.internal.domain.com"
},
"request": {
  "url": "https://app.internal.domain.com/app/",
  "headers": [
    [
      "User-Agent",
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
    ]
  ]
},
"title": "Blocked 'connect' from 'app.internal.domain.com'",
"type": "csp"
```

}

The reports come from multiple OS versions and browsers.

Anyone with an idea whats wrong here?

Comment: By looking to the CSP violation above, I also cannot spot anything suspicious. There are a bunch of "CSP-WTF" moments (see https://github.com/nico3333fr/CSP-useful/tree/master/csp-wtf) which result from in-browser apps (like e.g. Facebook, Instagram & Co). However, I could not find any evidence in the information provided...